# Textfield in webservice 

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, textbox

I have created Web-Service in asp.net with c# .
Now i want to pass some query where I want to give some input through user.
I have created methods with select and insert query.
But can I take input through some text box?

" I want to select Employee Names for some date and date will be the text box value.
Thanks in advance

When I run this webservice It is showing me this method.But When I try to INVOKE this method, error is displayed that "website can not display that page
"
i HAVE USED THIS CODE :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetEmps()
    {
        string s1 = txtMonth.Text;
        string getdays = "Select Emp from WorkingDaysinfo Where date = 's1'";
        con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getdays, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        String finalString = "{\"EMP count\":";
        finalString += jsonString;
        finalString += "}";
        return finalString;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like an easy task, just get the Text value of the textbox and pass it to the service call. Maybe you are talking about another problem

Comment: I have searched a lot but cant get the result.Hope someone will help..

Comment: Please, could you provide some source code for what you are trying?

Comment: Yes sir.I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, your web service code is throwing an exception and hence browser shows the generic error message. You can find out the exception details by putting break-point in your web service code or putting try-catch block to log the exception.

Based on your code and requirement, the most likely problem seems to be that you are probably passing a text string to a date column. Web service method can accept some input using method parameters (you cannot use controls from your form into your web service) and it can be passed to database using parameter. For example,

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetEmps(DateTime inputDate)
{
    // create a parameterized query
    string getdays = "Select Emp from WorkingDaysinfo Where date = @inputDate";

    con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getdays, con);
    // pass the parameter value 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("inputDate", inputDate);

    // rest of the code follows
    ..
```

Comment: Thanks for help.I can Enter the date now.But when I try ti INVOKE,same error is displayed

Comment: @misri, as explained in above answer - that' because of some exception occurring in your service code. Best way would be to debug your service code (add a break-point and hit F5 in Visual Studio).

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date",inputDate));

Comment: Sir I have got error on this line..I know I am asking silly questions But I am really new for this

Comment: @misri, what is the error description? BTW, parameter name (e.g. "date" in your comment) must match with the name (e.g. `@date`) used in the query!

Comment: Query :  string getdays = "Select Emp_ID from datetime Where date = @inputDate";

Comment: Here date is my database field name

Answer (score 0):

Please add web service reference in website application and try to pass parameters from their itself.